# changing html to C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a gallery that is dynamically meant to be created from a database, I have what the output of a gallery should look like but I am having trouble turning it into the dynamic C# that gets done in the background. Here is the intended output if there is one album, obviously if there are more then it will just put them under each other inside the galleries.

```
<div class="accordion" id="galleries"> inside here <\div>.

    <div class="accordion" id="galleries">
        <h3 class="accordion_header"><a href="">Panel 1</a></h3>
        <div class="accordion_body">
            <div class="navigation">
                <a href="#" class="prev prev-navigation">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a href="#" class="next-navigation">&rsaquo;</a>

                <div class="carousel carousel-navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li><div class="imgContainer"><img src="pic1.jpg" /><p>Ablum 1</p></div></li>
                        <li><div class="imgContainer"><img src="pic2.jpg" /><p>Ablum 2</p></div></li>
                        <li><div class="imgContainer"><img src="pic3.jpg" /><p>Ablum 3</p></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <br />
    </div>
```

I just want to know basically how to make this in just C# code, not using Response.Write() method. I don't know what C# types I need to use to get this to work... like what is the C# equivalent of a div? is it HtmlGenericControl? I don't know. but thanks for the help

Comment: I think in a .aspx file all html code will work...

Comment: Or put this in a reusable ascx.

Comment: Why do you all think that he is using WebForms? It could be MVC he is looking for.

Comment: You can manipulate HTML tags using the System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace, there are every classes that you need to dynamically make html controls..

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly, I have no idea waht MVC is, I am making it in VS2012 using master pages, so I don't even see any WebForms, tho that could be somewhere I don't know... I really am not sure.

Comment: @RameshSivaraman I thought there was but I don't know which HtmlControl represents which html div a tag href and everything like that.

Comment: @christiandev I did say which portion is dynamic. Everything inbetween the galleries div needs to be dynamic. but that isn't even the question, my question was how can I make that code fully C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `Page.Render` method if you want to output raw HTML:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.render.aspx

The ASP.NET `div` equivalent is the [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) control.

Also, as you said, `HtmlGenericControl` instantiated with `"div"` as input constructor parameter will be also a server control.

A `div` created with `HtmlGenericControl` is equivalent to `<div runat="server" />`.

Comment: thanks for explaining what HtmlGenericControl is, now I just need to know what the rest of them are... like that one with an 'a' as the tag and so forth.

Comment: @5tar-Kaster I would say you just need to go to the `System.UI.WebControls` namespace doc:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.aspx

Comment: thanks for the help, I was struggling a lot to figure this out and failed quite badly. You pointed me in the right direction so I marked this as the answer.

Comment: @5tar-Kaster That's the point :) Sometimes you need some guidance and that's all!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="accordion" id="galleries">
    <h3 class="accordion_header"><a href="">Panel 1</a></h3>
    <div class="accordion_body">
        <div class="navigation">
            <a href="#" class="prev prev-navigation">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a href="#" class="next-navigation">&rsaquo;</a>

            <div class="carousel carousel-navigation">
                <ul>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptImage">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <div class="imgContainer">
                    <img src='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' /><p>
                    <%--In Eval("ImagePath") replace "ImagePath" with your database field that represent Image path--%>
                        <%# Eval("AblumName")%></p>
                        <%--In Eval("AblumName") replace "AblumName" with your database field that represent album name--%>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<br />
</div>
```

in code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();//your datasource from database
            rptImage.DataSource = ds;
            rptImage.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to write HTML with C#, which is a question that have been answered quite a few time already.

You'll probably want to take a look at [HtmlTextWriter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmltextwriter) to begin with.

Comment: that is not what I want to do... hence I said without using Response.Write() method. I need this to be made entirely using C#, with no html. but the output of it will have that html in the browser.